# Building an app with express.js and node.js / GetHtml() with Javascript Elements

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to develop my first spa using node.js and express.js as framework. My only problem is that if I want to import a new view with getHtml() the  elements where transmitted as strings and not as a executable script components.

Can anybody help me what i have to do?

Thank you in advance.

edit 20.03.2023:
sure @pzaenger:
here is a overview of my structure, I will list the green marked up: [Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi0cN.png)

index

```html
<body id="loginpage">
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/static/js/index.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="/src/static/js/functions/gettime.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="/src/static/js/functions/pushinsert.js"></script>-->
</body>
```

index

```js
import landingpage from "./views/landingpage.js";
import loginpage from "./views/loginpage.js";
import manualinsert from "./views/manualinsert.js";
import timerecording from "./views/timerecording.js";

const pathToRegex = path => new RegExp("^" + path.replace(/\//g, "\\/").replace(/:\w+/g, "(.+)") + "$");

const getParams = match => {
    const values = match.result.slice(1);
    const keys = Array.from(match.route.path.matchAll(/:(\w+)/g)).map(result => result[1]);

    return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, i) => {
        return [key, values[i]];
    }));
};

const navigateTo = url => {
    history.pushState(null, null, url);
    router();
};

const router = async () => {
    const routes = [
        { path: "/", view: loginpage },
        { path: "/landingpage", view: landingpage },
        { path: "/timerecording", view: timerecording },
        { path: "/manualinsert", view: manualinsert}
    ];

    // Test each route for potential match
    const potentialMatches = routes.map(route => {
        return {
            route: route,
            result: location.pathname.match(pathToRegex(route.path))
        };
    });

    let match = potentialMatches.find(potentialMatch => potentialMatch.result !== null);

    if (!match) {
        match = {
            route: routes[0],
            result: [location.pathname]
        };
    }

    const view = new match.route.view(getParams(match));

    document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = await view.getHtml();

};

window.addEventListener("popstate", router);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.matches("[data-link]")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigateTo(e.target.href);
        }
    });
    router();
});
```

AbstractView

```js
export default class {
    constructor(params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    setTitle(title) {
        document.title = title;
    }

    async getHtml() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

timerecording

```js
import AbstractView from "./AbstractView.js";

export default class extends AbstractView {
    constructor(params) {
        super(params);
        this.setTitle("timerecording");
    }

    async getHtml() {
        return `
            <main id="timerecording">
                <div id="timerecordingtest" class="content text-center">
                    <h1 id="timerecordingTime"></h1>

                    <div class"justify-content-center"> 
                        <button type="submit" id="submitButton"  class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Kommen</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Gehen</button>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                    function getTime() {
                        
                        fetch('https://myurl') 
                        .then((response) => response.text())
                        .then((text) => {
                    
                            var utcDate = new Date(text);
                    
                        
                            var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, {
                                timeZone: Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone,
                                hour: 'numeric',
                                minute: 'numeric',
                                second: 'numeric'
                            });
                    
                            
                            document.getElementById("timerecordingTime").innerHTML = formatter.format(utcDate);
                            });
                        };
                    setInterval(getTime, 500);
                </script>
                </div>     

            </main>
        `;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @pzaenger I added all the necessary code. My problem is that the script part of the return value in the timerecording.js file is handled as html part and not as executeable script component